# Is there a way to make babel embed @babel/runtime?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` to transpile `async/await` statements with babel.

Only problem I have is that `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` needs `@babel/runtime` at runtime.

I just cannot find a simple way to get babel to inline the helper functions.

```
var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

var _regenerator = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/regenerator"));

var _asyncToGenerator2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator"));
```

What I want:

```
var _interopRequireDefault = /* resolved definition */

var _regenerator = /* resolved definition */

var _asyncToGenerator2 = /* resolved definition */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/11611) on the babel github project.

It is possible to embed *some* functions with the option:

```
"helpers": false
```

However `runtime-generator` cannot be embedded at the time.